# Class extends and validations in Java

Tags: java

**The exercise is this**

- Create an Employee class to represent an employee of a company. Add all relevant properties and behaviors that you might need but you have to include a salary property. Don’t forget to add getters and setters.
- Create an Intern class that extends from Employee. All the Interns have a salary limit of 20000 (constant). You must validate if an intern is created (or salary updated) with a bigger salary than the max. The max value is set.
- Write a program that creates 10 Employees and print it all the properties into a file named employees.txt.

I do it the first part, but I don't have idea to do the other parts with class extends and validations. I'm learning Java and I need help to understand better.

The first part is this

```
public class Employee {
    int idEmployee;
    String category;
    int salary;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public int getIdEmployee() {
        return idEmployee;
    }

    public void setIdEmployee(int IdEmployee) {
        this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the part you don't understand, and how did you try to implement it?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: The 2nd part, there are a phrase what I can't understand (All the Interns have a salary limit of 20000 (constant). You must validate if an intern is created (or salary updated) with a bigger salary than the max. The max value is set.) and I don't know to implement it. I have this (public class Intern extends Employee {
    double salary;

    public Intern(){
        super();
    }

    public double get_salary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(){
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}) but I don't know how I can implement this salary

Comment: The salary is set in the `setSalary` method. So that is where you have to implement the validation. Use an `if` statement to check if the value passed into the method is larger than the 20000 limit and then execute logic according to that.

Comment: Also: You don't have to redefine `double salary;` in the extended Intern class. Your Exmployee class already has a `int salary` field that any class that extends it inherits.

Comment: What setSalary method, in class extends or Employee class?